# static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css” does not exist

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I got with Django rest framework problem when I deployed Django project in production mode

if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myproj/api/v1/persons.json` everything is displayed correctly

if I go to `https://example.com/myproj/api/v1/persons.json?format=api` - layout breaks

in the page code I see:  `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

if I navigate to the path `https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css`
I see this error in the browser:

```
Page not found (404)

“/data/Projects/myproj_dev/Django/myproj/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css” does not exist

Request Method: GET

Request URL: https://example.com/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css

Raised by: django.views.static.serve

Using the URLconf defined in myproj.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/

myproj/

^static/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css, matched the last one.
```

I tried to find the file bootstrap.min.css and found it along this path:

/data/Projects/myproj_dev/Django/myproj_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css, but I don’t know what to do with it

Unfortunately, I was unable to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure `example.com` points to the same server? What do you mean by "layout" regarding **api** urls, **json file** urls? Am I correct that you put css files for your project into django packages install directories? Please show your settings.py and elaborate how your project is organized.

Comment: `in production mode` with Debug=false? have you configured your webserver (nginx, apache, iis) for serving those static files? did you call `collectstatic`?

Comment: Hello, Ivan thanks for the answer. The problem is gone. I added this string to settings.py STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')